# Audience style targeting based on User Profile

Tags: 2010, audience-targeting

Im looking for a way to target people for blogs or other information across my company who might be employed at multiple locations or moved locations.  The thought is that User is at Y city normally but is also interested in their co-workers at X city.  Is there a way to allow a user to choose what they want to be targeted by?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

There can be two solutions to this problem as I see it...

1- Add the user to their desired group:
What you can do is ask for a user to what locations he is interested in being the part of - I am assuming you will have Permission Groups for each of these locations and you will be using these groups in Target Audience right? So once user selects the locations[Groups], add the user programmatically to that group... Or if you say it will be a mess, you can apply an approval workflow before it actually happens!

You can look on [how to programmatically add a user in a Permission Group](http://geekswithblogs.net/madhawa/archive/2008/11/18/127171.aspx) and make a Visual Web Part for that!

2- If you have few content/pages, then apply Audience Targeting programmatically
You can [set Audience Target of Web Parts programmatically](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/02/set-audience-targeting-programmatically.html), so if you have few pages - you can use this method as well.. But even for this you will need the information for which locations the user is interested in, and then have to do it for each web part you want to set target audience on!

I hope this helps...